# In Visual Studio, How to keep Solution 1 using TFS and Solution 2 using GIT

Tags: git, tfs, visual-studio-2015

## Overview:

Visual Studio 2015 keeps changing my Source Control Plugin Selection settings back to GIT, regardless of which source control the current solution actually uses (i.e. TFS).

### Description:

I have GIT folders and TFS solutions under different directories on my dev laptop. When I open a TFS solution I need to change my options to select the correct provider. That is..

```
File => Source Control => Advanced => Change Source Control => Select and rebind all projects to TFS
```

..before I can use the context menu options from the solution explorer.

My solution file has a TFS section as follows, and I didn't have any problems until I introduced some GIT projects on my development laptop.

```
GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution
    SccNumberOfProjects = 4
    SccEnterpriseProvider = {4CA58AB2-18FA-4F8D-95D4-32DDF27D184C}
    SccTeamFoundationServer = http://excluded:8080/tfs/development
    SccLocalPath0 = .
    SccProjectUniqueName1 = BTL\\BTL.csproj
    SccProjectName1 = BTL
    SccLocalPath1 = BTL
    SccProjectUniqueName2 = BTLDataLayer\\BTLProject.csproj
    SccProjectName2 = BTLDataLayer
    SccLocalPath2 = BTLDataLayer
    SccProjectUniqueName3 = BTLDataLayer\\BTLProjectDBSpecific.csproj
    SccProjectName3 = BTLDataLayer
    SccLocalPath3 = BTLDataLayer
EndGlobalSection
```

Comment: Are you mixing Git- and TFVC-controlled projects in the same solution? Otherwise it should simply works.

Comment: No, different solutions, different folders. The MS Git Provider keeps resetting itself as the default. I think this is because under my user home directory, or somewhere, I will have a .git folder and it "sees" this and thinks ah right.. this guy uses GIT so I'll set his source control configuration as such. Thats' not the case though.. I, as like most, have global GIT settings and I think these are what VS is seeing.

Comment: For me visual studio auto detects correctly. I have all my tfvc projects mapped to /sources/ and git projects to /repos/... Do you maybe have an overlap?

Comment: I think that is exactly the problem @MrHinsh, while I don't have any direct overlap, a parent directory of my TFVC also contains a GIT repository. I've since moved my TFVC content to a totally different location and can now work again in peace. For example, TFVC under c:\development\tfvc and GIT under c:\development\git.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no good answer here. It can't be achieved. Moreover, VS can't detect the used version control system automatically. You will simply have to go in and manually change you visual studio source control provider settings before you open the project.

Here has been a featured request in Voice of VS. You can also vote for it.

> **Ability to configure Source Control settings per project**
>   http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2520134-ability-to-configure-source-control-settings-per-p

Comment: This is not the answer. Question is per solution and not per project. Visual Studio will automatically detect the version control system configured for the Solution that you open.